# Having an error in my strings.xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, string

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">DataGush Alpha</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string-array name="menu_items">
        <item >Top Lists</item>
        <item >Map</item>
        <item >Search</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

I am getting these errors:

```
[2014-03-02 15:31:32 - DataGushAlpha] W/ResourceType(64288): ResXMLTree_node header size 0 is too small.
[2014-03-02 15:31:32 - DataGushAlpha] C:\Users\anshv_000\workspace\DataGushAlpha\res\values\strings.xml:12: error: Error parsing XML: mismatched tag
[2014-03-02 15:31:32 - DataGushAlpha] C:\Users\anshv_000\workspace\DataGushAlpha\res\menu\main.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').
```

Comment: Is that the whole file? strings.xml:12 and you only posted 11 lines.

Comment: Clean & build project again?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the XML file in a simple text editor for errors.
Sometimes when you let Eclipse/ADT autocomplete **inline** it just leaves some garbage there that is not visible in the editor somehow. It happens frequently to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have had some problems with incorrect new line characters sometimes, please check the file and ensure that the xml is correct. 
You should see whats wrong in the `string.xml` file in eclipse, shows up as a error in the editor or you could look in the problems view. If the error is not shown in the `string.xml` file then it's not a problem with the file, in this case the `R` file hasn't been updated correctly and therefore the string resource cannot be found, this happens for me from time to time. The solution to this is usually to clean and build the project, alternatively close and open the project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the `space` between `item` and `>`

```
    <item>Top Lists</item>
    <item>Map</item>
    <item>Search</item>
```

and check this tag `'action_settings'`: there is no String with this tag